# Why and how add Model as a dependency in NestJS?

Tags: javascript, nestjs, multi-tenant

I'm trying to do [this tutorial](https://www.learmoreseekmore.com/2020/04/nestjs-multiple-mongodb-databases.html) and it doesn't work for me. When I run the code, I get this error:

```
ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the TestService (?, AnimalsModel). Please make sure that the argument StudentModel at index [0] is available in the TestService context.

Potential solutions:
- If StudentModel is a provider, is it part of the current TestService?
- If StudentModel is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within TestService?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing StudentModel */ ]
  })
```

I believe this is the code that I need to change(?)

```
    @Injectable()
export class TestService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel('Student') private readonly studentModel: Model<Student>,
    @InjectModel('Animals') private readonly animalModel: Model<Animal>,
  ) {}
```

[Git Repo](https://github.com/SamLevinSE/multi_ten)

Answer (score 1):

1. you've got `TestService` in an `imports` array. DOn't do that. `provides` never belong in the `imports` array, only modules do
2. To create the provider for `@InjectModel('Student')` you need to add `MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Student', schema: StudentSchema })])` to the `imports` array of the module that contains `TestService` (presumably `TestModule`) so that Nest can go and create the dynamic provider that you want to inject.

---

Edit after receiving the repository

[You're using named database connections](https://github.com/SamLevinSE/multi_ten/blob/test_multi_ten_2/src/app.module.ts#L18) so you need to use those same connections in the `@InjectModel()`.  `@InjectModel('Student', 'myWorldDb')`. [Just like the docs show](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb#multiple-databases)

Comment: Jay, please check the repo. I removed the TestService from the imports, still the same error.

Comment: Where in the repo is the `TestService`?

Comment: My bad, it's another branch:
https://github.com/SamLevinSE/multi_ten/tree/test_multi_ten_2

Comment: I had to change some more stuff, but now it works. Thanks Jay <3

Comment: Not related to this question, but, could you please check this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74224103/how-to-do-multiple-mongodb-nestjs